# Wordpress ignoring custom permalinks structure

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have a custom structure for permalinks (Wordpress 3.9.1 + Types 1.5.7) like this:

> /%post_id%

But wordpress returns me something like this:

> /post-type/%postname%

It seems like wordpress overwrites my post_id param. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
/%post-type%/%postname%/

If that doesn't work check the codex [Wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)

I'd also look into using tags, categories, or taxonomies as a possible solution (again, check the codex-I've got no idea)

Comment: Your solution is not what I'm looking for. I only need post_id (http://domain.com/post_id)